# using regex to stack multiple rasters in a folder

Tags: r, geospatial, r-raster, terra

I have numerous raster files in a single folder and need to stack all of the files that contain the phrase "rrs" for each unique date/sensor/location. I was able to extract out those use unique file names using:

```
all_files <- list.files("D:/ACOLITE_Output")

unique_files <- all_files %>% str_extract('^(.*?).Rrs') %>% na.omit() %>% unique()
```

Now I need to create a raster stack for each of those unique strings (e.g., "S2A_MSI_2021_09_17_18_35_19_T11SMS_L2W_Rrs") and their corresponding bands.  Something akin to

```
  for(i in 1:length(unique_files)) {
     raster<-str_extract(all_files,"S2A_MSI_2021_09_17_18_35_19_T11SMS_L2W_Rrs*") %>%

     RasterStack <- terra::c(RasterStack,raster)
     terra::writeRaster(RasterStack, paste("D:/"+unique_files[i])) 
  }
```

Comment: FYI, for code block formatting in your question you want to either use the three backticks on a blank line before and after your code OR indent 4 spaces, but not both.

Comment: For your question, it would help a lot if you could make it reproducible. Could you share 2 or 3 entries of `list2` and give an a few examples of the bands that correspond so we can better understand the needed process?

Comment: Lastly, I'd mention a style point that you seem to be using `list` as names for objects that seem like they are not of class `list`, but rather are character vectors. Everything can still work, but it will make your code a little difficult for experienced R users to read when you label a variable with a different class.

Comment: I tried to edit the text to remove any naming convection problems. Here are three results of the unique files: [1] "PlanetScope_0f33_2017_09_25_16_28_39_L2W_Rrs"
[2] "PlanetScope_0f33_2017_09_25_16_28_41_L2W_Rrs"
[3] "PlanetScope_0f36_2017_09_25_16_27_35_L2W_Rrs"

Comment: Here are the first two full file names:  [15] "PlanetScope_0f33_2017_09_25_16_28_39_L2W_Rrs_505.tif" 
 [16] "PlanetScope_0f33_2017_09_25_16_28_39_L2W_Rrs_546.tif" 
 [17] "PlanetScope_0f33_2017_09_25_16_28_39_L2W_Rrs_625.tif" 
 [18] "PlanetScope_0f33_2017_09_25_16_28_39_L2W_Rrs_809.tif"  [29] "PlanetScope_0f33_2017_09_25_16_28_41_L2W_Rrs_505.tif" 
 [30] "PlanetScope_0f33_2017_09_25_16_28_41_L2W_Rrs_546.tif" 
 [31] "PlanetScope_0f33_2017_09_25_16_28_41_L2W_Rrs_625.tif" 
 [32] "PlanetScope_0f33_2017_09_25_16_28_41_L2W_Rrs_809.tif"

Comment: There are other files but only those contain "Rrs" so I would need some regular expression using those unique file names to then select only the 4 full files names (bands) associated with each of the unique files

Comment: Thanks for changing the `list` names. Feel free to edit this other helpful information into your question too. If it will make your question clearer, no need to leave it down here in comments with less formatting.

Comment: And thanks for the examples of the unique file values and the `all_files` examples. Within your loop, you can get the matching files from `all_files` for the `i`th unique file with `matching_rasters <- all_files[str_detect(all_files, fixed(unique_files[i]))]`. I'm not sure where to go from there as the rest of your code doesn't look syntactically valid and I'm not familiar with the `terra` package so I can't make any guesses about what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You have most of the pieces you need above, except it appears grouping your files (the 'regex'). To increase flexibility, you might use `all_files <- list.files("D:/ACOLITE_Output", full.names = TRUE)`, as this returns the full path and file name, so you don't have to have the files in your working directory. Once you clearly explain which files go together the regex can be worked out. The below addresses the mechanics thereafter to read and combine rasters in `terra`.

To stack or combine all of these, they all have to have the same characteristics, i.e. same extent and resolution.

`for` loops require a 'receiver' on the left hand side of `<-` and the receiver needs to be allocated/established outside of the loop. This is where processed objects reside after they've been read in from file and received their 'signature', in this case `SpatRaster` `terra`.

```
rasl <- list() # empty receiver - with short name for easy typing
for (i in 1:length(unique_files)) {
rasl[[i]] <- terra::rast(unique_files[i])
}

class(rasl[[1]])
[1] "SpatRaster"
attr(,"package")
[1] "terra"

# now combining - I just have three in my local list, you have many

rasl_stack <- c(rasl[[1]], rasl[[2]], rasl[[3]])
rasl_stack
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 3600, 3600, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.0002777778, 0.0002777778  (x, y)
extent      : 33, 34, 35, 36  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
sources     : ALPSMLC30_N035E033_DSM.tif  
              ALPSMLC30_N035E033_MSK.tif  
              ALPSMLC30_N035E033_STK.tif  
names       : ALPSMLC30_N035E033_DSM, ALPSMLC30_N035E033_MSK, ALPSMLC30_N035E033_STK
```

If all to your liking and no errors, write it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a loop. You can do

```
x <- terra::rast(unique_files)
```